# Why is the x free in the lambda

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have following lambda expression:

```
x λ x. x
```

This is a function application, but why `x` is free variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is not free in the lambda, but it is free outside of the lambda. Or, more simply, in

```
x (\y. y)
```

`x` is free but `y` is not. Variables are free just when there is no enclosing lambda that binds them; since there is no lambda enclosing the `x` at all, there is certainly no lambda enclosing the `x` that also binds `x`.

Comment: What about `(λ x. x (λ y. x y z y) x) x y`, is `x` inside the second lambda is free? I think not, because it is bound to the outer lambda?